# Como definir o arquivo de inicialização em um projeto HTML?

Tags: netbeans

Sempre que crio um projeto HTML no Netbeans ele cria um arquivo **`index.html`** e até ai normal, o problema mesmo é quando eu quero criar um novo arquivo HTML dentro desse projeto. Eu crio o novo arquivo e quando vou depurar ou executar ele não abre esse arquivo criado somente o **`index.html`**. Como faço para abrir esse novo arquivo e não o **`index.html`**?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que acontece? Não entendi...

Answer (score 1):

No NetBeans 8. No tabulador de projectos onde se encontra o seu projecto listado, escolher o projecto em causa. Depois:

1. Com o ponteiro do rato em cima no projecto pressionar o botão direito do rato
2. Do menu que aparece escolher properties
3. Abre um gestor de propriedades do projecto
4. Escolha a opção "Run"
5. Na caixa de input alterar o "Start File" para o ficheiro que pretende executar sempre que execute o projecto.

NOTA: por defeito o Netbeans define que o index.html é o ponto de partida de qualquer projecto HTML5. Por experiência é bom manter alguns defaults e este é um deles, mas se quiser alterar e especificamente para um projecto apenas aqui tem a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Quando se cria qualquer projeto web no Netbeans automaticamente é definido um arquivo para ser o inicializador, em projetos HTML5 o **`index.html`** será esse arquivo.

Você pode definir como o projeto será executado alterando as propriedades do projeto. Para isso, clique com o botão direito sobre o projeto HTML e selecione *propriedades*:

[image: propriedades do projeto]

Na aba "*executar*" é possível definir o arquivo de inicialização (que por *default* é o **`index.html`**) além de outras configurações de execução:

[image: propriedades de execução]